# fetch_feed works on localhost but not on server

Tags: rss, feed

There is [one similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/troubleshooting-fetch-feed-and-simplepie), but I can't seem to get round to what's going on. So any help appreciated...

The following code works just fine on localhost, but when on the live site I get the following: WP HTTP Error: connect() timed out!

```
            <?php if (function_exists('fetch_feed')) { ?>
        <?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
        $feed = fetch_feed('http://participmontpellier.wordpress.com/feed/');
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $feed ) ) : 
            $limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(2);
            $items = $feed->get_items(0,$limit);
        endif;
        if (!$items){
            echo $feed->get_error_message(); 

        } else {
            foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
                <h4><?php echo $item->get_date('F j, Y'); ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></p>

            <?php }
        } ?>
     <?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is out the scope of this site. See the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first check or set the timeout window on the online install, keyword `max_execution_time`.

Also a hint to the feed, there have a issue, often also a problem for the connection: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fparticipmontpellier.wordpress.com%2Ffeed%2F

Also a chance is a plugin or function inside the Theme, that cut the connection.

The last point, that you should check this two constants. Ther should be on `true` value for connections.

- `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL`
- `WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS`

More background about WordPress and Offline Topic can you find in [this source](https://github.com/bueltge/WP-Offline) of the plugin. But you must check the contrary ;)